# Cannot Find Symbolh(Java)

Tags: java

I'm having an  issue with the compiler with the following message:

```
public class CircleJava2 {
    public CircleJava2(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
}
```

The problem is the variables are defined within the scope of the parameters. When using `this.variable = variable`, the method should recognize the variable passed through to be used within the method body as a statement.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `radius` is not declared as an instance member, so `this.radius` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Add `private double radius;` right after the class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `radius` as a class member, as mentioned in the comments:

```
public class CircleJava2 {

    private double radius; // here

    public CircleJava2(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
}
```